# Excel) Fill in the receipt with the purchase data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

#### I'm trying to fill in the **receipt** with the **purchase data**, but it's not working.

1. **purchase data**

[image: purchase data]

this is the purchase data, and price list for each items.
With these data, I have to fill the receipt like this.

2. **receipt**

[image: receipt]

And, I managed to put names on the receipt with the customer number with vlookup,

but I don't know how to fill the others.

I have to fill it only with information about the **products sold.**

Can anyone give me some tips about what function to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there's little guidance on what exactly you tried and expect I found it interesting to try something just for the fun of it.

it's necessary to have office 365 for this solution:
You could use the following formula in `N3`:
`=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FILTER(Table1[[#All],[Sticker]:[Pen]],INDEX(Table1[[Sticker]:[Pen]],MATCH(O1,Table1[Name],0),)<>""),(Table1[[#All],[Name]]="Name")+(Table1[[#All],[Name]]=O1)))`
Followed by the following formula in `P3`:
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(N3:N8,$K$1:$L$5,2,0),"")`

Or - I liked this solution best myself, but it's way overdone for it's purpose - use the following in `N3`:
`=LET(order,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(FILTER(Table1[[#All],[Sticker]:[Pen]],INDEX(Table1[[Sticker]:[Pen]],MATCH(O1,Table1[Name],0),)<>""),(Table1[[#All],[Name]]="Name")+(Table1[[#All],[Name]]=O1))),price,VLOOKUP(INDEX(order,,1),$K$1:$L$5,2,0),colOrder,COLUMNS(order),IF(SEQUENCE(1,colOrder+1)<=colOrder,order,price))`

@Mark Fitzpatrick: yeah, used a new bought laptop this time.[image]